# Heap Sort Error: expression must be a pointer to a complete object type?

Tags: c++, function-call

I am implementing Heap Sort for an assignment. We have to do it the same way she did in class with her pseudocode, or else we dont get credit.

In my Max_Heapify function, im getting an error when I call my Left() and Right() functions, that say "***expression must be a pointer to a complete object type***".  Im going directly off of psedocode, so im not sure what is causing this error, can anyone help?

```
void Max_Heapify(int heapArray[],int i)
{
int n = SIZE;
int largest = 0;
int l = Left[i];//<--Error here on Left
int r = Right[i];//<--Error here on Right

if(( l <= n) && (heapArray[l] > heapArray[i]))
{
    largest = l;
}
else
{
    largest = i;
}

if( (r <= n) && ( heapArray[r] > heapArray[largest]))
{
    largest = r;
}

int temp;
if(largest != i)
{
    temp = heapArray[i];
    heapArray[i] = heapArray[largest];
    heapArray[largest] = temp;

    Max_Heapify(heapArray,largest);
}

return;
}
```

...........................................................................................

Here are the Left() and Right() functions if it helps at all

```
int Left(int i)
{
return (2*i);
}

int Right(int i)
{
return ((2*i)+1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left & Right are functions; your code is using them as if they were arrays.  To call a function, use (), not [].

Answer (score 1):

You need `Left(i)` and `Right(i)`, not `Left[i]` and `Right[i]`

Answer (score 0):

```
int l = Left[i];//<--Error here on Left
int r = Right[i];//<--Error here on Right

int l = Left(i);//should be
int r = Right(i);//should be
```

Answer (score 0):

it is an error because we use () to espress function call in C++.
you have to change

```
int l = Left[i];
```

into

```
int l = Left(i);
```

Comment: @Mike Gordon also you may want to remove heapsort tag, because this is not algorithm related, you may add function call tag

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the best possible implementation of heapsort look into the linux kernel.

```
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/sort.c
```

I remember staring at it when I was new to C so that I could absorb perfection.